# c# TCP/IP communication error: Address requested non valid in own context

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

as suggested in an other SO question, I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ObcGBT4ZWEU
This works on lan but when I try over internet with IP taken from any web service, and using port 80, it gives the error in the image
[image: error]

The italian part is "Address requested non valid in own context" (I dunno if this would be english text for this error)
The error comes out with "Start" button (button1). the code is:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            epLocal = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(textLocalIp.Text), Convert.ToInt32(textLocalPort.Text));
            sck.Bind(epLocal);

            epRemote = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(textFriendsIp.Text), Convert.ToInt32(textFriendsPort.Text));
            sck.Connect(epRemote);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1500];
            sck.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epRemote, new AsyncCallback(MessageCallBack), buffer);

            button1.Text = "Connected";
            button1.Enabled = false;
            button2.Enabled = true;
            textMessage.Focus();

        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exp.ToString());
        }

    }
```

the socket variables are declared as global:

```
    Socket sck;
    EndPoint epLocal, epRemote;
```

and initialized as:

```
        sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        sck.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
```

Any suggestion?! Thanks!!

edit: i successfull get an englsh error!!!
[image]
In italian versione i've the precise line too and it is:

```
sck.Bind(epLocal);
```

Comment: Do you have a valid IP that your using?  If it works on the local lan, it sounds like you may be using the wrong IP address.  Are you connected in a corporate environment, or at home?  If at home, you might want to look at your local IP using http://whatsmyip.org/ since most likely, your router is doing NAT translation.  It could also mean that the remote IP is not listening on that port.  You could try to do a telnet <remote_host> <remote_port_number> and see if you connect.  What line is the throwing the exception?

Comment: Also have a look here http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/233487-tcpclient-exception-requested-address-not-valid-its-context

Comment: go to https://www.grc.com/shieldsup then press proceed ,scroll a little down to where you can select port scans"there you can see you're internet provider ip" and scan you're computer for open ports if needed.

Comment: @Mike i have a function that take the client owner IP (than 2 guys using the program should share the ip). I'm using http://checkip.dyndns.org/   i will try to telnet that so to say if the other guy has to forware port 80 to his pc, or even using a new port. (8080 ?)
Creator I made this test, 80 is on "stealth" and is "http" ... dunno what this could means... haha
By the way, the line that throw the error is 
sck.Connect(epRemote);
thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't told us what the value of `textLocalIp.Text` is, but the problem likely lies there.

You can't bind to just any IP address, it has to be the address of one of the network cards in your computer, or `0.0.0.0` for "any".  Trying to use your router's public IP address or your friend's IP address will not work.

Most of the time, you should skip calling `Bind` and just let Windows pick the local address and port.  If you want a specific port, then bind using `INADDR_ANY` which is `0.0.0.0`, along with that port.

Comment: Well i supposed i had use the same ip the friend use to connect to me, as local ip, and vice versa. Using the ip I find with ipconfig in cmd (the ipv4 ip addres I think, the 192.168.x.y ) it works perfectly!! Then I can do it automatically with a function to tale local ip, as shown in the youtube tutorial.
Thanks a lot!!